# if, elif, else and input not printing on the console properly

Tags: python

I have a question about if, elif, else and input. When i try to run this code on the Visual Code Studio integrated Terminal/Console or the command prompt there's a bit of an error, this is what I mean

```
Name = input("What is your name?")

if Name == "Tom":   
  print("Hello, me.")
```

And then this happens next,

When I type "Tom" as my choice it immediately goes to this 
"Hello what is your name? Tom" I press enter, then it says the following
"Press any key to continue....."
and it doesn't give me the "Hello, me."

Any particular reason why it does this? I've watched several YouTube tutorial videos on it and everyone seems to have if, elif, else and input working just fine. If anyone could give a noob some guidance it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it do the same thing when run via the command-line? Integrated code-running systems don't always handle user-input correctly.

Comment: I do not see any "Hello what is your name?" or `else` or `elif` in you code. Please include _all_ relevant code.

Comment: First, what python arena you using? In 2.7 you should use raw_input

Comment: You are not running the code you think you are. This code would not do what you have described.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the `if/elif/else` statement, you should consider the Python tutorial: [if Statements](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)

Your code works just fine:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
if name == "Tom":
    print("Hello, me.")
```

But, you should take care of uppercase/lowercase, for instance:

```
What is your name? Tom
Hello, me.
```

But:

```
What is your name? tom
```

=> you get nothing because `"tom" != "Tom"`.